# Склеить один бинарный файл в конец другого

Tags: delphi

Как склеить файлы последовательно в один.
Один в конец другого и т.д.
Всего 541 файл каждый по 5 мб.
Чтобы память не вылетала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TFileStream` и его метод `CopyFrom` вам в помощь.

Создаете свой один FileStream пустой. Затем создаете еще один FileStream из первого из Ваших 541 файлов. Копируете его содержимое в первый FileStream (методом `CopyFrom`). Закрываете FileStream. Создаете новый для следующего файла и т.д. в цикле. Когда файлы кончатся, закрываете свой первый (основной, в который копировали) FileStream.

Profit :)

Comment: Спасибо, память не будет есть программа?, знаю что мемористриам ест

Comment: Если Вы будете удалять за собой объекты, которые больше не нужны, то память никуда не денется.

Answer (score 1):

- открыть "новый файл" на запись.
- в цикле
- открыть очередной файл
- в ещё одном цикле

  - вычитывать блоками оптимального размера (видимо по 4-8кб)
  - записать в "новый файл"
- конец цикла записи
- обработать хвост (не все файлы кратные 4-8кб)
- закрыть поточный файл
- конец цикла по файлам
- закрыть "новый файл"

расход памяти будет небольшой, скорость приемлемая.

Comment: Зачем так сложно? `CopyFrom` скопирует все содержимое файла за раз.